# Drawing SysML/UML diagrams in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, uml, diagram, sysml

I have several hardware componets that i have to represent dynamically using SysML diagrams. The diagrams must be shown in the gui and furthermore there has to be the possibility to save them in a directory. All libs and programms i found so far are converting the files of the project to UML, but i need a kotlin lib that draws what i am modelling in the code, not the code itself.
The best output would be a svg file but regarding the current situation i would appreciate everything. Does somebody know a lib for this task or a workaround that could help?